# How to pass names of partials in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I want to include a file, whose name is in `page.var`. How can I get get it included?

If the partial in page.var is written in markdown, how can I get it processed into html as it is included?

I've tried  `{% include {{page.var}} | markdownify %}`, and every variation I can think of - and mostly I get no output and no error message.

I'm using the standard Jekyll - version 0.11.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

It's now possible thanks to the usage of `{% include {{my_partial}} %}`, as per alexpeller's response.

Old answer, before Jekyll allowed this:

> You can't do that in Jekyll. The `include` directive expects a string; it doesn't "process" its argument. You can't even assign the filename to a regular liquid variable and include it. It has to be a string.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I suspected. It appears that Jekyll is missing two important features - processing of partials, and parameter passing to include.

Comment: This is no longer accurate

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/) this is now possible:

> The name of the file you wish to embed can be literal (as in the example above), or you can use a variable, using liquid-like variable syntax as in  `{% include {{my_variable}} %}`. Note that unlike usual liquid variable syntax, you cannot have spaces inside the curly braces.

Comment: That exact line throws an error in Jekyll: 
`Liquid Exception: Invalid syntax for include tag. File contains invalid characters or sequences: Valid syntax: {% include file.ext param='value' param2='value' %} in _layouts/component.html`